# Angular 5 environment variable access issue

Tags: angular, environment

While playing this example https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart, I run into some issues. 
code is https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart/blob/master/src/app/service/user-login.service.ts

```
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
```

line 26

```
if (environment.sts_endpoint) {
        clientParams.endpoint = environment.sts_endpoint;
    }
```

will have environment 'undefined' when debug through.

I found that in debug mode, `[scope].environment_1.environment` has everything - the question is how to access in code?

This is in Angular5 context.

Comment: Please provide the bit of code where you ran into the issue...

Answer (score 0):

after reviewing other code in the same project, I noticed that congnito.service.ts has code that bypassed same issue, it defines a static variable, then the static variable (_REGION) can be passed around instead of the environment.region. But I do not really understand the mechanism behind. It looks violates the closure principle if can not use environment.region.

export class CognitoUtil {

```
public static _REGION = environment.region;
```